# Shell - Increment number in for loop

Tags: linux, shell, loops, if-statement

I want to prepare a shell script using if and for loop.

The concept of this script is, I have few folders(name+number) like below.

f0

f1

f2

f3

f4

Script looks like,

**count=0**

So the script will move the first folder to another folder (folder name is f so, f + count= f0 ),

```
mv f0 /tmp
```

If it is a success then it'll *print success* and close the process.  Else it'll move 2'nd folder like `f+count+1=> f+0+1 ==>f1`

```
mv f1 /tmp
```

If this step get success then *print success* and close the process, else again increase the count=count+1 `f+count+1 => f+1+1 =>f3`

```
mv f2 /tmp
```

Comment: What's your question? There must be hundreds of tutorials that show how to do arithmetic in the shell.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: Why do you need to use a counter? Just do `for dir in f*; do ... ; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
#!/bin/sh

count=0;
while ! mv "f$count" /tmp 2> /dev/null  
do count=$((count + 1))
done
echo "Success"
```

Comment: This is a good start.  Note that it will likely enter an infinite loop if count exceeds the max count of an extant directory.  Easy enough to fix with `test -d f$count || break`, or similar.

Comment: Seems its try to move all the folder, I have updated the question. If f0 is moved then my process is done, because sometimes the folder numbers are different . So If f0 moved -> close all, else try to move f1.